# Call methods through macro expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have this code:

```
class A {
public:
  bool has_foo() { return true; }
};

int main() {
  A a;

  CALL(a, foo);
}
```

I'd like to call the method `has_foo` through macro expansion:

```
#define CALL(object, method) do { object.has_ ## method ## (); } while(0)
```

The code above compiles on MSVC, but fails with GCC.

I would like to use macro expansion in order to avoid runtime overhead.

Comment: Drop the second `##`. `foo(` is not a valid token. Anyway, what is this "runtime overhead" of which you speak? Compared to what alternative? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: A macro performs direct token substitution before compiling.  Why do you think using a macro avoids runtime overhead?

Comment: *"I would like to use macro expansion in order to avoid runtime overhead."* Which overhead do you want to avoid ? BTW, IMO, `a.has_foo();` seems clearer than `CALL(a, foo);`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Looks like you are trying to reinvent `std::invoke`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with

```
#define CALL(object, method) do { object.has_##method(); } while(0)
```

Comment: Incidentally, a *better* expansion would be `CALL(object, method) ((object).has_##method())`.  This a) allows the macro to be used in an `if`/`for`/etc; b) copes with things like `CALL(*ptr_to_a, foo)`